# Keep common/redundant xml attributes in separate file for reuse

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have to keep adding these attributes for padding over and over again in almost every element

```
<TextView
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/less_padding"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/less_padding">
```

What I want is to put these 4 lines in a separate file and then use that file as a single line of code to apply whenever I want in any element. Is it possible?

Comment: Create a style and apply the style to your elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file `styles.xml` in your `res/values/` directory, and put this in it:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="CommonPadding">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/padding</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/padding</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/less_padding</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/less_padding</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Then, in your various layout files, you can do this:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/CommonPadding"
    ...
    />
```

Comment: Should I put this "styles.xml file in res folder or one of the folders in res directory?

Comment: res->values->styles.xml